# Remove the last part of a string after the last "." in R

Tags: regex, r, gsub

Imagine we have a list of variable names like following:

```
ls<-c("apple.mean", "orange.mean", "orange.sd", "apple.pie.mean", "orange.juice.n", "orange.juice.p%")
```

How can we remove the last part (after ".") in each element so we can get:

```
"apple" "orange" "orange" "apple.pie" "orange.juice" "orange.juice"
```

Note that there might be "." inside the names but I don't want those words to be split.

I was trying to use `gsub("\\..*$", "",ls)` but it omits everything after the 1st dot. I'm not sure why the $ sign is not working here. Any ideas?

```
> gsub("\\..*$", "",ls)
[1] "apple"  "orange" "orange" "apple"  "orange" "orange"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try

```
sub('[.][^.]+$', '', ls)
#[1] "apple"        "orange"       "orange"       "apple.pie"    "orange.juice"
#[6] "orange.juice"
```

Comment: Thank you! I saw your earlier edits. Either way works!

Comment: @Hao No problem.  The difference in my code is that it is matching the `.` followed by all non `.` till the end of the string and replace it with `''`

Answer (score 2):

Given that this is the equivalent of removing a file extension you could use

```
library(tools)
file_path_sans_ext(ls)
```

Comment: Oh,my. This is actually a very smart move for this case